# Handle Exceptions in Python Function's signature

Tags: python, typing

I wonder if I have designed my script correctly (it works so far) because of a loop of warnings from which I cannot get out.

I am trying to define a function that either is able to parse a JSON response from a website or it simply terminates the program. Here my code:

```py
from requests import get, Response, JSONDecodeError
from typing import Any
from sys import exit

def logout() -> None:
    exit()

def get_page(url:str) -> dict[Any,Any]:
    try:
        response: Response = get(url)
        page: dict[Any,Any] = response.json()
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(e)
        logout()
    return page

try:
    result: dict[Any, Any] = get_page("https://stackoverflow.com/")
except Exception as e:
    #handle exception
    pass

print(result['something'])
```

Pylance informs me that `page` (as in `return page`) and `result` (as in `print(result['something']`) `is possibly unbound`.
As far as I understand there are different possible workarounds to this problem, but none of them solves entirely the problem:

- When moving `return page` before the `except` statement, `mypy` raises a `Missing return statement`.
- If I ignore the "error" from `mypy`, Pylance informs me that I should anyway sign my function specifying that it should return `dict[Any,Any] | None`.
- Changing the return signature to `dict[Any,Any]` means that outside the function `result` should be `result: dict[Any,Any]|None` but then `result['something'] is possibly unbound` and `Object of type "None" is not subscriptable`
- initializing `page = {}` at the beginning of the function is a possible solution, but what if `page` is a custom `class` which need some parameter that I cannot provide?
- I could `raise` an `Exception` from within the function if there would have been a way to inform Pylance about this possible behaviour (is there?)

My point is: the function will NEVER return `None` right? So, am I doing something wrong? How do you deal with this? Should I refactor my function?

Comment: I don't think typing is silly in Python.

Comment: There is nothing preventing `get(url)` from raising a `JSONDecodeError` so you could have `page` be undefined.

Comment: You should put `return page` in an `else` block of the `try/except`. That way, `page` is only accessed if there's no exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[typing.NoReturn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn) is used for functions that never return. For example:

```py
from typing import NoReturn

def stop() -> NoReturn:
    raise RuntimeError('no way')
```

So you should type hint the return value of `logout()` with NoReturn:

```py
from typing import NoReturn

def logout() -> NoReturn:
    exit()
```

Comment: The OP does not ask about functions that never return *at all*; they only mention functions that will never return the value `None`.

Comment: This doesn't fix `"result" is possibly unbound` in Pyright

Comment: @ekhumoro `logout`, in fact, never returns at all. Ideally, a type checker could recognize that `return page` cannot be reached if `logout` is called in `get_page`. In practice, figuring that out in general might be a bit much to expect from a type checker.

Comment: @chepner I don't deny that. What I was trying to get at was that the answer proposes a solution without attempting to address all of the issues the OP raised (i.e. unlike [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950816/984421) that has since been posted). However, perhaps the point is moot now that the OP has accepted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

> the function will NEVER return `None` right? So, am I doing something wrong?

Yes and yes. A function that gets a webpage has no business exiting your program. Imagine you want to use it again in some later code but this time, you want to try again in 30 seconds. Well, the function is going to exit the program regardless, so you'd need to rewrite the function at that point.

Instead, let the exception propagate and have the **top-level code** exit where necessary.

Secondly, the reason `result` may be unbound is that you're ignoring any exceptions when setting it. That'll mask any error (even a typo in your code, like `logou()`) and make a different error appear later, so don't do that.

Thirdly, `logout` will never return, so we'll use [`NoReturn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn), [as koviubi56 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950143/4518341).

Additionally — and this is a whole other can of worms — JSON is not constrained to `dict`; it can be `list` or a scalar or null (`None`). `response.json()` is actually typed as `Any` [in the typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stubs/requests/requests).
On the other hand, the keys will always be `str`. For the sake of example, I'm just going to assume `dict[str, Any]`.

And, beside the point:

- Errors should be printed to stderr instead of stdout. `sys.exit` can do that for us, so we can pass the error message via `logout`.
- `exit` is a builtin, so use a different name for `sys.exit` to avoid confusion. I'll use `exit_`.

```
from requests import get, Response, JSONDecodeError
from typing import Any, NoReturn
from sys import exit as exit_

def logout(message: str) -> NoReturn:
    exit_(message)

def get_page(url: str) -> Any:
    response: Response = get(url)
    page = response.json()
    return page

try:
    result: dict[str, Any] = get_page("https://stackoverflow.com/")
except JSONDecodeError as e:
    logout(str(e))

print(result['something'])
```

Try it online on the [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&code=MQAgTgpgjgrhDOAXeIAmEBmBLAdlxWA9jigEYCG8EqIxIiAngA4IAW1AUKK4ok-AC4A9EIDm%2BVjFIA6AMaEAtkKYNErYkMYt47VJsgQhC8riFIp8IZFgJkV6HCTwOHWQBtKKAPoAlB7YBRAA9ZCCYCYgAKAHkAZQCwMEIwAEoBDhBMkFBIeCZiKgEQPzyCiBAAHxAAOWIIDKyc-yQivxskSpAABUgmckhUNsdETtqceqzstEwQLy9cfDnIhszQSao3DAAaEAAqftFBWlIAKwhZRB3rYdbmkaqesP7qIdtRupAAXhBpX6uEfIkCC3UpA97jL4-X4rKYpEAAWgAfDU6kVftIYTC%2BvBnK4PDjZgBJHAAN3IbiwqAAUrFotUEkkwJFfHdgqFwkQcGkoRj3J4QDS6QARc6EdAM5LM4lkinU2n0xLJbnolx8gklQGFGHoDAgE7wKIw9YQTZbI2NPZmyaTUDuI5aCAAbUF1RF8nQYAAuuDyt90VbratjmcLl51IQANZFADC5I8pDcTsdqCwF0dAEEcAwdpmGJ7PTms96qmNfTyA4HQH0wFQvBg3IRyIgY3HyAmk0gvYW8z7If7zUHq7XcM2QLG3PHE47HZ2CyBc8WURC-X8B1MhxAvPISIhyDhR%2BPJx3EF350XeyvpBXraBCKdzogvH0sDWw4RIy2J22p46KUhHYgMBMFOubdvmc4Lhe5ZrqAuy7BGADuqBHKBMJwkiZ4MGi0IcDqICiBAiDLJMMBgG4RSdp0pCqAg15Vv05AKEcXhdAxTFQaWdGWjCoCoE25BFF4Qr8VB-Y2iA7DkB6zEABIQFJEA1gAsuQTBMLgoiiau4nyJGWAILc7TING74RvpVL9J0XgACoQEEiAqWpGlaVePEgNgibMQAYlgnkuVx5AwGognpkFrD%2BW5BAKBAhBBYJ1lYNFsX3EuZZiRacaEAhXgDC%2BD5HKQ75uH22kWkwSRBPpzG2fZjnqTgmklh8l5ceGEayaZ8DEkwQUReJnbyQoRSFYQxVNcu0HiSSilYBgWGzAAajNc19RaoRgKOXjRopKWliVrnifqxBFMS8gKMBhHlONaWruhyIamU6TiSqMKQIBYA4MUAJlJEKQuKA8KA-97lJAo4B3CgiX5Bt%2BGETsD1AjsLpumKEASmAHAYKD9DMM5UPJCMoEon4704Jj2PwAwkPnQTIB2fgICUHTlWPi4eENqIyWRNFOLkARFEnndxOEaROBPVk9OPtzCDwHzEB-bhMwEY%2BfQEZEpHkSAnZC7m4uZLkmrAl9oJUJCyvq2Rf2TKrZYG2U0hHTgv2vSLH0gDbLgnlhLvwDAbijimaadmBZuEU%2BcuRAARDwfCCCISDkLIEaENNYD1llciKEIkd-XZ7IjMjorioqYCMygwIwhzXOdpE8sK%2BVI6RLkfuII6ADkBrRWoGlt56KRAA) or [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=f671e96f2d496443bfd4acf00d0e7815)